# How to move graphene resolve methods to different files?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I have the following code. Query is my root schema.
If I have only one `profile` it's ok to have resolve method inside of query. But what if schema is too big?
Is anyway to move `resolve_profile` inside of Profile object type?

```py
import graphene

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
  profile = graphene.ObjectType(Profile)

  def resolve_profile(self):
    return ...

class Profile(graphene.ObjectType):
  firstName = graphene.String(graphene.String)
  lastName = graphene.String(graphene.String)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with graphene but I think Query is also treated as any other object type while defining the schema, so every field should have its own resolver in its type itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't move `resolve_profile` into `Profile` but there is another technique to handle having a large schema.  You can split your query into multiple files and inherit each of these files in `Query`.  In this example, I've broken `Query` into `AQuery`, `BQuery` and `CQuery`:

```
class Query(AQuery, BQuery, CQuery, graphene.ObjectType):
   pass
```

And then you could define `AQuery` in a different file like this:

```
class AQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    profile = graphene.ObjectType(Profile)

    def resolve_profile(self):
         return ...
```

and put other code in `BQuery` and `CQuery`.

You can also use the same technique to split up your mutations.